# Pi to Arduino Serial Communication: Repeating character on LCD

Tags: pi-3, usb, serial, arduino, lcd

I'm trying to send multiple characters (two digit numbers) from a Raspberry Pi 3 (Python 2.7.9) to an Arduino Uno via USB. The Arduino then prints these numbers to a 16x2 LCD panel.

So far, I can send a single character, but it repeats this character on the entire LCD panel. If given more than one character, it repeats only the first character. I've futzed around with it a fair but, bit it seems that whenever I add complication, it breaks entirely. I've done a fair amount of research to get this far, but must admit my knowledge of Python is limited. I've attached my Arduino sketch and Python code. They're both fairly simple as they will be added to larger programs. As a note, I've connected a 47µF capacitor from the reset pin to ground on my Arduino so it won't auto-reset. Can someone please point me in the right direction here? I feel like I'm getting close and would really appreciate any help.

Arduino sketch:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> 
const int rs = 6, en = 7, d4 = 8, d5 = 9, d6 = 10, d7 = 11;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);
char count;
boolean data;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 lcd.begin(16, 2);
 lcd.print("Ready for Data...");
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    count = Serial.read();
    data = true;
  }
    if(data == true){
      lcd.print(count);
    }
}
```

Python Code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
val="5"
ser.write(val)
ser.close
```

[image]

Comment: Playing around more, I can see that it's a timing issue. For example, when I use a while loop and a delay to send data to the Arduino, it seems to work. Now the problem is that it keeps repeating. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Maybe having the Arduino send a conformation message back, which would exit the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to @Joan's answer, but different.

I would initialize the "data" variable with "false", then after printing the character, set "data" to "false" again.  This allows you to only set the "data" variable when You want, not at every loop.

You will need to have the Arduino "ready and waiting" before running the Python code.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the capacitor, though.  I don't see anything that would cause a reset, but I don't know Python.

Answer (score 0):

I detest that style of indenting.  I have used a natural style which to my mind makes the code intention clearer.

```c
void loop()
{
   if (Serial.available() > 0)
   {
      count = Serial.read();
      data = true;
   }

   if (data == true)
   {
      lcd.print(count);
   }
}
```

Once data is true the character will be printed forever.  Simplest solution is to set data = false before the initial if.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but when added, the LCD is unresponsive and reads only "Ready for data...". I've tried it before the if and inside as the last line...

Comment: That is a separate problem, the Pi end is only sending one character which is presumably sent before the Arduino is ready.

Comment: Should I sleep the pi for some amount of time? Change the if serial.availabe to a while?